How to implement QR code Scanning in ReactJS using zxing?
I tried QR code scanning using many ways, like react-qr-reader, react-qr-scanner but all these have dependency issue with latest react version.
Hence I tried zxing , it is working but it is not identifying the QR, I am not sure if there is anything missing in this code.
import React,{ useState } from 'react'
import AdminNavBar from './AdminNavBar'
import { useZxing } from "react-zxing"

const ScanQR = () => {

    const [result, setResult] = useState("");
    const { ref } = useZxing({
      onDecodeResult(result) {
        setResult(result.getText());
        console.log(result)
      },
    });

  return (
    <div>
        
        <AdminNavBar/>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12">
                    
                <>
                <video ref={ref} />
                <p>
                    <span>Last result:</span>
                    <span>{result}</span>
                </p>
                </>                  

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default ScanQR


check for error using:
if (status === 'error') {         return <div>Error: unable to access camera</div>;     }

There is no error or camera access issue, camera opens up but doesn't seem to identify the QR code. Result is empty. @Darkpsinight

It seems you might be missing a few essential parts like (initializing the camera stream) and (handling errors).
import { BrowserBarcodeReader } from '@zxing/library';

const ScanQR = () => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState('');
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const codeReader = new BrowserBarcodeReader();
        codeReader
            .decodeOnceFromStream(undefined, 'video')
            .then(result => {
                setResult(result.text);
                console.log(result.text);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });

        return () => {
            codeReader.reset();
        };
    }, []);

    return (
    <div>
        
        <AdminNavBar/>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-12">
                    
                <>
                <video ref={ref} />
                <p>
                    <span>Last result:</span>
                    <span>{result}</span>
                </p>
                </>                  

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    )
}

export default ScanQR


This is not working for me, I installed the @zxing/library and tried your code but the camera itself is not starting. Could you give me the entire code ?

@jobygeorge maybe you need then to give Browser Permissions to use camera in browser settings.
Additionally, you may want to consult the documentation or community resources for the @zxing/library to see if there are any specific requirements or troubleshooting steps for camera access.
